# How can I get the timestamp value in Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

How do I get the timestamp value? I already set enable and store as true, I can see it on Sense, but was not able to get it.

```
  {
       "cubx": {
          "mappings": {
             "organization": {
                "_timestamp": {
                   "enabled": true,
                   "store": true
                },
                "properties": {
                   "address": {
.
.
.
```

I can see it...

```
GET /abc/organization/1234?fields=_timestamp

{
   "_index": "abc",
   "_type": "organization",
   "_id": "1234",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "fields": {
      "_timestamp": 1430535032967
   }
}
```

But I can't retrieve it...

```
public GetField getTimestamp(Long companyId) {

        GetResponse response = client
                .prepareGet(index, type, companyId.toString()).execute()
                .actionGet();

        return response.getField("_timestamp");
```

It returns null. I already read a lot of posts here but didn't find an example to get the value to a object. I also tried to use script_value as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985434/3750221) but without success.

Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `GetResponse response = client
                .prepareGet(index, type, companyId.toString()).setFields("_timestamp").execute()
                .actionGet();`

Comment: If you don't specify the fields to return it doesn't return any fields (but probably returns the "source" instead. As per Andrei's comment, just specify the field you want to return and it should work.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked! @Andrei, please post your comment as a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: One more thing: the return is something like `org.elasticsearch.index.get.GetField@4e8ddff8`. Why it's like this? Do I have to convert it to another object type?

Comment: Using this I was able to got the value: `long timestamp = ((Number) response.getField("_timestamp").getValue()).longValue();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use it like this `GetResponse response = client .prepareGet(index, type, companyId.toString()).setFields("_timestamp").execute() .actionGet();`.