# How to get a ES document with timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to access the document's timestamp.
How can I do?

I use

```
localhost:9200/cbborder/order/_search
```

but the result without timestamp.

[image]

Like this
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning the timestamp field in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653676/returning-the-timestamp-field-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: The `@timestamp` field is in the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ES are you using? If it smaller than 5.0 then you can use the following mapping to generate the timestamp for every document:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

But this was removed in the newer version of the ES i.e after v5.0.
But they have provided other option like pipeline ingests.